# Xcode - A single Layout per device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I was just wondering if there is a way to do a single storyboard layout for each IOS device in xcode. This is because i am having trouble using auto layouts with my app that i am building.

Cheers, 
Steve

Comment: forget about it. it is against the whole point of using storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use auto layout. You probably *should* but there's nothing forcing you to.

If you want to have a different layout for different sizes of device, you need to learn about *size classes*. Again, this is nothing to do with auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend per device. It will be an absolute nightmare to maintain and build but I know some apps are designed differently for iPhone and iPad- how to info here if you're interested:

https://irawd.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/xcode-6-separate-storyboard-for-ipad-and-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to explain layouts in several words, I suggest you to look at Stanford ios8 course:

"8. View Controller Lifecycle, Autolayout" .

The second half part will answer your question.

https://itunes.apple.com/cn/course/8.-view-controller-lifecycle/id961180099?i=335430612&mt=2